# How can I get current version of app from play store

Tags: android, android-studio, version

I have try many online solution but didn't work for me.newVersion keep returning null.

```java
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if(!isFinishing()) {
        String currentVersion = AppUtil.getPackageVersion(UpdateActivity.this, appItem.mPackageName);
        try {
             newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appItem.mPackageName + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select("div.hAyfc:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
                    .first()
                    .ownText();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
        return newVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace and try with that?

.get()
.select(".hAyfc .htlgb")
 .get(5) 
.ownText();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).